# Discrepancies in the evaluation of $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{x^2-1}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2-1}\,dx\qquad (0<a<1)$$ by residual methods.

My approach has been that there are no poles in the upper half-plane but the integrand has a pole at $x = -1$ and at $1$. These have been treated separately and going through the motions, I get a real value (Good, as integral is real!)

However, on checking the value against what Wolfram (and others) give, reveals that this is a divergent integral! Can anyone assist me with an explanation please ?

Comment: The integral is not divergent. For the assumptions you wrote, the result is

$$\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi  a}{2}\right)-i\right)$$

Comment: @AlanTuring it diverges around $x=1$

Comment: I am puzzled that the result you quote is not real and has an imaginary part

Answer (score 1):

The integral is divergent at $x=1$, however the limit $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left( \int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{x^a}{x^2-1}\,dx + \int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2-1}\,dx \right)$$ does exist, and this is precisely what you are computing with residue methods. One often calls this "integral" the Cauchy principal value. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value))

Comment: @C.Bubussy. my calculation gives a value (a real value) of pi/2*(sqrt(2) +1). Is this wrong/right

Comment: Well I didn't do the computation but I'm surprised that you have no occurence of $a$ in your answer. Obviously the answer should depend on $a$.

Comment: @C.Bubussy. Apologies, I have taken a = 0.75. Thank you. As I said this is a 'real' result for a 'real' integral ....but my attempt at verifying it have cast doubt on my answer. Hence my request fro advice.